# Alternative Menu content on mobile in Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, menu, nav

Here is the code I am using to show my menu. As you can probably see, the menu items are images as opposed to text. What I want to do is revert to showing text links rather than images for mobile and small screen devices when you hit the toggle button. I have no clue!?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default header-sketch">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html#top"><img class="logo" alt="CarShare Logo" src="img/car-logo.png"></a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right desktop">
                    <li><a class="toscroll" href="#top" title="Home"><img alt="Home" src="img/home.png"></a></li>
                    <li><a class="toscroll" href="#about" title="About CarShare"><img alt="About CarShare" src="img/about.png"></a></li>
                    <li><a class="toscroll" href="#signup" title="Sign Up"><img alt="Sign Up" src="img/signup.png"></a></li>                
                </ul>
            </div><!-- End Navbar Collapse -->
        </div><!-- End Container Fluid -->
    </nav><!-- End Nav -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add class `hidden-xs` to images and 'visible-xs' to text.
More you can read here about [responsive utilities of bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities)
eg.

```
<a href="#">
    <span class="visible-xs">Home</span>
    <img class="hidden-xs" alt="Home" src="img/home.png">
</a>
```

Comment: Sorted. Perfect. Thanks.